# Determine whether the functions are uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have the definition of uniform continuity as such: A function $f: D → R$ is uniformly continuous on $E$ contained in $D$ iff for every $ε>0$ there is $δ>0$ such that if $x,y$ are elements of $E$ with $|x-y| < δ,$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < ε.$ If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$, we say $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I just don't know how to actually apply these concepts to the given definitions.

Answer (score 1):

a) $f(x) = x \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$ is uniformly continuous. Strategy is to split $(0,\infty)$ into two intervals and show $f$ is uniformly continuous in each, then put it all together.

We may set $f(0) = 0$ and the resulting extension is continuous. So $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ and this is a closed bounded interval so $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, hence is uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$. Now for $[1,\infty)$, we note that the derivative $f'(x) = \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$. So it is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$ by MVT. Now if $x \in (0,1]$ and $y \in [1,\infty)$, then use $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(1)| + |f(y)-f(1)|$ to bound the difference. This shows the whole function is uniformly continuous.

b) Not uniformly continuous. To show it simply find an $\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, there is $x_\delta, y_\delta \in (0, \infty]$ with $|f(x_\delta)-f(y_\delta)| \geq \varepsilon$. Simply take $x = e^{\frac{1}{2}+k}$ and $y = e^{k}$ and let $k \to -\infty$.

Comment: Thank you immensely for the help! For b) I'm a little confused about the ε part...what is the ε value that I am concluding is sufficient to show that the definition of uniform continuity does not hold?

Comment: So a function is uniformly continuous on $D$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in D$, $|x-y| < \delta $ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$. So to show it is not uniformly continuous, we take the negation of this statement, i.e. find an $\varepsilon > 0$, such that for all $\delta > 0$, we can find some $x,y$ with $|x-y| < \delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq \varepsilon$.